# How to get all values where a certain Key matches in Dataweave 2.0?

Tags: mule, dataweave, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

**Payload :**

```
[
{
    "Contacts": "123456,098765",
    "Emails" : ""
},
{
    "Contacts": "ABC123",
    "Emails" : ""
}
]
```

How can I get a list of all emails from the below array of objects where the contact Id matches from each row in the payload? (Expected output below)

**Variable accConts**

```
{
    "queryResponse": [
        {
            "Email": "test123@test.com",
            "SalesforceId": "123456"
        },
        {
            "Email": "test@test.com",
            "SalesforceId": "098765"
            
        },
        {
            "Email": "ABC@test.com",
            "SalesforceId": "ABC123"
            
        }

    ]
}
```

**Expected Output:**

```
[
{
    "Contacts": "123456,098765",
    "Emails" : "test123@test.com, test@test.com"
},
{
    "Contacts": "ABC123",
    "Emails" : "ABC@test.com"
}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTH..

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json



var qResp ={
    "queryResponse": [
        {
            "Email": "test123@test.com",
            "SalesforceId": "123456"
        },
        {
            "Email": "test@test.com",
            "SalesforceId": "098765"
            
        },
        {
            "Email": "ABC@test.com",
            "SalesforceId": "ABC123"
            
        }

    ]
}


--- 


payload filter ($.Contacts != null) map using (iter = $$) {
    "Contacts" : $.Contacts,
    "Emails": (qResp.queryResponse filter (payload[iter].Contacts contains $.SalesforceId)) reduce ((item,acc = "") ->  (acc ++ "," ++ item.Email)[1 to -1]
    )

}
```

Comment: I am getting error for `map using (iter $$). This is the error I get : `Invalid input "map using (iter = $$) ->"`

Comment: Actually, I figured out, I used just the Map and it worked. I will post the updated answer.

Comment: When you used the variable ( using the keyword using) what did your script look like ?

Comment: I tried exactly what you had, but it gave me above error. The one I posted below worked fine as rest of my payload was constructed that way anyway so.

Comment: I see what you might have done. You probably put a -> after the using declration, something akin to payload map using (iter = $$)-> {...} which would blow up exactly the way you got the error. Otherwise if you use the script as is, it should work fine.

Comment: that would explain it, thanks for taking time. I am getting error when the `Contacts` value is null, how can I avoid that since that field won't always have a value in it?

Comment: Sure. you could filter them for Contacts != null. I will update my answer with that.

Answer (score 1):

I accepted Salim Khan's answer as he guided me in the right direction and the logic to get emails worked. I just needed to rework the map logic,

```
payload map (row, index) -> {
    "Contacts" : row."Contacts",
    "Emails" : (qResp.queryResponse filter (row."Contacts" contains $.SalesforceId)) reduce ((item,acc = "") ->  (acc ++ "," ++ item.Email)[1 to -1]
    ),
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this comaprision helps

[image: Works fine]

[image: Results in error]

Comment: This could be it because I tried in dwlang so that makes sense. Thank you appreciate that.

Comment: Salim, not sure if these picture links are going to stand the test of time.

Comment: They don't need to. This was just a screen grab for that very moment , to show that the script worked as expected in playground as well. The script is up there as a selected answer, in case folks want to refer to it!!

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to add a slightly more succinct solution to show another approach.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

var qResp =
{
    "queryResponse": [
        {
            "Email": "test123@test.com",
            "SalesforceId": "123456"
        },
        {
            "Email": "test@test.com",
            "SalesforceId": "098765"
            
        },
        {
            "Email": "ABC@test.com",
            "SalesforceId": "ABC123"
            
        }

    ]
}

--- 

payload map (value) ->
    {
        'Contacts':value.Contacts,
        'Emails': qResp.queryResponse[?(value.Contacts contains $.SalesforceId)]..Email joinBy ", "
    }
```

Comment: That is very neat actually. I am going to try this too